# Crystal Reports print if NOT blank

Tags: crystal-reports

OK...so there seems to be another problem now.
I have used the following code:

```
    IF ({rmadtl.ShortChar01}) = ""
    OR
    (ISNULL ({rmadtl.Shortchar01})) 
    THEN 
    TRUE
```

for the Serial Number which is from the rmadtl table and is ShortChar01 field. This works and hides any serial numbers that are empty strings.
BUT...

```
    IF ({rmadtl.ShortChar03}) = ""
    OR
    (ISNULL ({rmadtl.Shortchar03})) 
    THEN 
    TRUE
```

does NOT hide the Dates. It still shows "Date:" and also "0"
I am not sure why this is happening for the date field but not the serial number field. Does anybody else know why this is happening?

Comment: what kind of field type are both fields?

Comment: @SunWKim they are both string values

Comment: What do you mean by "does NOT hide the Dates"? Shortchar03 is a date field?

Comment: @SunWKim yes, "Date Code:" is a text object and is the label. ShortChar03 is the date field which should output the date, if a date was input. They are both string values.

Comment: @SunWKim what I need is for it to ONLY print the Date Code if NOT blank.

Comment: Are you placing this code in supress condition? And from where you are getting 0...as thre is no 0 in your formula

Comment: @Siva the 0 is just for testing, along with the blank (null), as opposed to having an actual serial number or date.

Comment: And for some reason, the Senior Developer was sitting here playing around over and over, wracking his brain...

Comment: He put this line of code in:  if {@test} = ";" then
    true   and it made the Date Code label and field disappear   HOW BIZARRE!! WHY?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: Ok that means problem solved?

Comment: For the time being...I don't want to say for sure (yet)...but I would like to know why when that line of code is put in, it does not print but if you put the correct code that should and does belong there, it does not??

Comment: First thing `It still shows "Date:` in this case your condition will fail because since there is date there no need to `supress` hence you can see data.. now if you paste your code for `0` will try to advice

Comment: @Siva thanks so much...give me a little time to get that to you and I would be more than happy to!